# Bootstrap 4 input group and jQuery Iris color picker target option

Tags: jquery, color-picker

When using [iris](http://automattic.github.io/Iris/) on my targeted `#color_picker` input, the color picker is inserted after my `#color_picker` input, which breaks the color picker styling because [bootstrap 4 input group](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/input-group/)'s are styled using [flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

See my fiddle to see bad it looks because of bootstrap 4 input group flex css.. https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/gvj1o5ac/ (see notes at end of question)

I would like to be able to control where iris inserts the color picker pallet html when called.

After reading [iris documentation](http://automattic.github.io/Iris/) `target` was the only thing that I could see that could allow me to control this. So I tried this option ([see fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/at964oz0/))..

```
target: $(this).parent('.form-group')
```

The [full code below](https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/at964oz0/) just causes and error and I cant find a way to target or insert the color picker else where.

```
$('#color_picker').iris({

  // change where iris palette is inserted after
  target: $(this).parent('.form-group'),

  // do stuff when color is changed
  change: function(event, ui) {

    // change the prepend indicator
    $(this).siblings().find('.input-group-text').css('background-color', ui.color.toString());

  }

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/at964oz0/ (fiddle for code above)

**Snippet**

```js
$('#color_picker').iris({

    // do stuff when color is changed
    change: function(event, ui) {

      // change the prepend indicator
      $(this).siblings().find('.input-group-text').css('background-color', ui.color.toString());

    }

});
```

```css
.input-group-prepend .input-group-text::before  {
  width: 18px;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://dev.joshmoto.wtf/iris/dist/iris.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap input group mark up below -->

<div class="container pt-3">
  <form>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-5">
        <div class="input-group">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text" style="background-color:#00e4bc"></span>
          </div>
          <input type="text" id="color_picker" class="form-control form-control-lg" value="#00e4bc" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

**Note**

You are probably thinking it does not look that bad, but sometimes it looks like the screenshot below, not sure why it appears ok in the question snipped but if you edit my question code snippet, it looks like..

[image]

But if I drag the iris color picker element outside the input group in the DOM using the chrome inspector..

[image]

..it then looks sweet like this screenshot below, hence why I want to retarget where it is inserted/appended..

[image]

Also if you know bootstrap 4, you will notice the right border radiuses on the input are lost. This because the input group styling knows there is a child element after the input. Hence why these radiuses are lost.